# How to mean of Thread number, Ram-up, Loop count in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

- List item

I confused to Ram-up and Loop count in Jmeter that how to different

- List item

Case: run 100.000 requests
Thread number: 10.000
Ram-up: 100 seconds
Loop Count: 10

---

As i know: For data above: 1 second will have 100 request running(10.000/100) so 10.000 request need to 100 seconds, that right
So how about loop 10 times?? It'll take 100 second * 10 = 1000 seconds (~17 minutes) to end 100.000 request
But actually I run scripts on JMeter that only take 100 seconds (1 minutes 40 seconds) to complete 100.000 request

---

Can anybody explain to this?

---

Thanks

Comment: Ramp up period is just the max time 10,000 threads will start, after that they will run in parallel

Answer (score 0):

1. JMeter starts the "thread number" within the time, specified in the "Ramp-Up". For your "use case" 10000 threads and 100 seconds means that new 100 threads are added each second. See [JMeter Ramp-Up - The Ultimate Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-ramp-up-the-ultimate-guide) article for more information if needed.
2. Once thread has started it starts executing [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) upside down.
3. When all Samplers are executed the thread starts next iteration
4. When there are no more iterations to complete the thread is being shut down
5. When there are no more running threads the test ends

The duration of the "iteration" depends on the number of Samplers and the application response time, we cannot tell you how long your test will be running. You can limit execution time in [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group)

[image]

but in this case you won't have the guarantee that all samplers/iterations will be complete